# Ansible Playbook issue

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am using `win_choclatey`for windows application deployment, but the job keeps running I think it expecting a password to install application, so where can I declare in my Playbook ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [expect](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/expect_module.html) module in your playbook. There are examples in the documentations of how to do it.